# How do you import rows by matching columns that are not ordered the same?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to import rows from sheet1 to sheet2 by matching the columns as the columns are not ordered the same.  What is the best way to do this?

I.e., if I had a main sheet with the following columns:
[image: target sheet]
and I wanted to add rows from a sample sheet with columns not in the same order:
[image: source sheet]
So that I result in the main sheet with all rows appropriately ordered by original column:
[image]

Is there a function to do this, or should I script my own?  Thanjks.

Comment: Can you please provide more details about this? What did you try till now? What research did you do? Is there a formula (or script) that you are working on? Can you clarify what is your purpose? (a screenshot, or even better, a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, could be useful).

Answer (score 2):

As stated on the comment, when you ask questions please provide any findings you may have gathered from researching or trying formulas so we can better help you.

Now in context to your post, there's a formula you can use to achieve what you want using QUERY function. `=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:E,"Select A,B,E,D,C",0)`

You may have to change the `Sheet1` to the name of the main sheet if you changed it but the end result would look something like below.

**Initial Sheet:**
[image]

**End Result when data is Queried**
[image]

**Quick Edit:**

Here's an updated formula based on the update on your question. I've patterned the additional sample screenshots to match the order on your data. Basically what you can do it use query function inside an array to combine both data.

Here's the formula you can use to achieve that (This assumes that both sheets are inside the same spreadsheet): `={QUERY(Sheet1!A2:E,"Select B,A,D,E,C where A<>''",0);QUERY(Sheet2!A2:E,"Select A,B,C,D,E where A<>''",0)}`

Feel free to change the sheet name on the formula to match your sheet accordingly.

Here's sheet #1
[image]

Here's Sheet 2
[image]

End Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi there, I've updated the answer to match your situation. Please check the Quick Edit section of my answer. Thanks.Sorry bout the blabber data on the sheet btw. Was in a hurry so I added random data on the sheet. But I'm sure you get the point of the output anyway.